# Software to manage divisions and inventory on a building

Tags: open-source, 3d, educational

Wondering if there is any software to help planning divisions in a specific building (in this case a school/University), their dimensions, objects inside/inventory (such as tables, chairs,...).

Ideally, but not limited to, the following requirements:

- 3D, but 2D would also do the work. It would be helpful that one could define the location of, let's say, a desk and a chair in a specific division.
- OpenSource.
- Ease of use, or relatively low learning curve.

I believe that with the architectural plan of the building I could do this in Blender/Unity/Unreal, but I am looking for something less time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to look into Sketchup.

https://www.sketchup.com/

From 100+ EUR/year, free limited web-based version that requires registration.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JoeWilliamsen. It is way faster to build something in Sketchup, in comparison to Blender.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially missing: How does it meet the requirements, what makes it recommendable, what about costs – and last but not least, where to find it?